# Perform action after data has been rendered

Tags: meteor

I have a chat app and I'd like to scroll to the bottom of the messages once they've been loaded. The problem is that I don't know when they've been loaded.

I have a helper called messages that returns a cursor of Messages, but a spinning symbol is shown while the messages are loading. The code I'd like to run when the first time the messages are rendered is:   $('.chat-panel').animate({scrollTop: 999999});

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I think I may have worked out an answer. I'll stick the relevant code in rendered of a single message template

Comment: actually this doesn't work, since it will scroll when the first message is rendered, but not the first set of 15 messages

Comment: well having tried it does work...

Answer (score 0):

Put each message in its own template and scroll to the bottom of the chat panel when the first message is rendered.
You can use a boolean variable to make sure this only happens once.